# Offline video freezes every few minutes

Tags: windows-7, video, freeze

I have a custom computer running (legal, updated) Windows 7, 8GB Ram, 1-yo Graphics Card. My system runs on a new SSD and my media is stored on a <1-yo HDD.

Recently when I am watching (non-HD, offline) videos on VLC player, the video would freeze randomly (once every few minutes). The freeze would last 10-20 seconds, and then it would play for a fraction of a second, freeze again, for a few times until it becomes normal again.

During the freeze, other programmes are functioning normally. And the computer does not feel like it is lagging.

I restarted yesterday and it did not happen during playback then. I put the computer to sleep during the day today and the issue surfaced again tonight.

I am worried this might be a harddrive issue even though my media drive is less than a year old.

Has anyone encountered similar issues or have an idea what the cause of this was?

Comment: Copy one of the affected videos to a new location and play it from there.

Comment: Thanks but no luck. I tried several video files from multiple folders. Correction: I have 2 HDD media drives, and files from both drives are having this issue.

also, I found that I cannot pause or stop the video during the freeze. the command i give only happens after it unfreezes

Comment: How about the same videos in another player, like Potplayer?

Comment: Are you utilizing VLC version 2.2.4?  We use that exclusively at work with a wide variety of video files, many of them several GB in size.  Our workstations have standard 1 TB SATA hard drives.  That being said, we definitely don't see any problems like that.  Troubleshooting 101:  the part where you emphasized that _"My system runs on a new SSD"_ stands out as the most recent configuration change.